# Criar e-mail com texto e HTML não funciona | Espaçamento no e-mail

Tags: html, python, email, outlook

Estou com dificuldade de criar um e-mail no pandas que vai enviar um texto e um HTML.

Prezados,

Teste de envio;

•   **Através dos telefones**: XXXXXX - XXXXXXXXX

•   TESTE

Rejeitado (s):

**AQUI VEM UMA TABELA HTML QUE SAI CORRETAMENTE NO CÓDIGO**

Tentei da forma abaixo, mas sem êxito na formatação.

```
    ## Função para envio do e-mail
    
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = emailpara
    mail.Subject = 'Message subject'
    mail.Body = 'MESAGEMMMMMMMMMMMMM'
   
    corpo = ("Prezados," + "\n Teste de envio;" + "\n \n \n Através dos telefones: XXXXXX - XXXXXXXXX" + "\n TESTE " + "\n Rejeitado (s): ")
    
                                        
    mail.HTMLBody = (corpo) + delcolunas.to_html(index = False).format(corpo)
        

    mail.Display()
else:
```

Comment: O que vc quis dizer com pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitua o `\n` por `<br>`

Explicação: você optou pelo `mail.HTMLBody`. Se o `body` (corpo) do email é HTML, você deve usar tags do HTML.

Espero que ajude

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!!!!!! Eu realmente me perdi nesta parte e faz todo sentido.